# Difference between meta cache tag and htaccess caching?

Tags: css, html, .htaccess, caching

I currently have this in my `.htaccess` file for resource caching:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Do I also need the `Cache-Control` meta tag on my pages for these rules to apply? i.e.

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">`

Answer (score 1):

Both are setting different headers and values, the result in the browser will be the same whichever method you are using. The main difference is in the type of files each can apply to:

```
*a <meta> tag can only appear inside an HTML document; consequently, you cannot use it to control cache validity on non-HTML files (such as images), and it's possible that something would download the file without processing the HTML and spotting the tag.*

*the Apache Header directive (not part of mod_rewrite) can be applied to any file that Apache is serving, whether it is dynamically generated or not. This can include images, static HTML, CSS, and JS, plus whatever content you generate with PHP.*
```

The only disadvantage of the Apache directive is that depending on your setup and experience with Apache's configuration rules, it may be difficult to maintain more complex rules for different bits of data.

You may want to give it a try using PHP like below:

```
the PHP header() function can affect any file that you are serving dynamically with PHP. This could include, for instance, plain text or XML files, but might not include an HTML file you'd uploaded fully formed to your server. You could pass static files, including images, through PHP, but this would be an inefficient way of serving them.
```